# How to add onClickListener() to a onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm creating a search bar using `Firebase`, everything is OK, but I don't know how to set a click listener to the `RecyclerView`. I need to show more information when I click on the results. I hope you can help me. Here is my main code and my `SearchAdapter`:

Main Code:

```
public class SearchCousesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef, myRef2, databaseReference;
private String userID;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

EditText SearchCoursesETXT;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

ArrayList<String> titleList;
ArrayList<String> lugarList;
ArrayList<String> costoList;
ArrayList<String> duracionList;
ArrayList<String> aprobacionList;
ArrayList<String> URLimagenList;

SearchAdapter searchAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_couses);

    SearchCoursesETXT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTXTSearchCour);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RVResultsCourses);



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){
                // setUserData(user);
            } else {
                goLogIn();
            }

        }
    };
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Courses");
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    lugarList = new ArrayList<>();
    costoList = new ArrayList<>();
    aprobacionList = new ArrayList<>();
    duracionList = new ArrayList<>();
    URLimagenList = new ArrayList<>();


    SearchCoursesETXT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()){
                setAdapter(s.toString());
            }else {
                titleList.clear();
                lugarList.clear();
                costoList.clear();
                duracionList.clear();
                aprobacionList.clear();
                URLimagenList.clear();
                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
            }

        }
    });

}

private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {



    databaseReference.child("Courses").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            titleList.clear();
            lugarList.clear();
            costoList.clear();
            duracionList.clear();
            aprobacionList.clear();
            URLimagenList.clear();
            recyclerView.removeAllViews();

            int counter = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String uid = snapshot.getKey();
                String title = snapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                String place = snapshot.child("state").getValue(String.class);
                String costo = snapshot.child("costo").getValue(String.class);
                String duracion = snapshot.child("duracion").getValue(String.class);
                String aprobacion = snapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                String URLimg = snapshot.child("uri").getValue(String.class);

                if (title.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())){
                    titleList.add(title);
                    lugarList.add(place);
                    costoList.add(costo);
                    duracionList.add(duracion);
                    aprobacionList.add(aprobacion);
                    URLimagenList.add(URLimg);

                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter == 20)
                    break;
            }

            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchCousesActivity.this, titleList, lugarList, costoList, duracionList, aprobacionList, URLimagenList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);


}

private void goLogIn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

**Here is my SearchAdapter:**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {

String[] mDataset = { "Data", "In", "Adapter" };

Context context;
ArrayList<String> titleList;
ArrayList<String> lugarList;
ArrayList<String> costoList;
ArrayList<String> duracionList;
ArrayList<String> aprobacionList;
ArrayList<String> URLimagenList;






class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    ImageView course_Image;
    TextView course_Title, course_Place, course_Cost;

    public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        course_Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseImage);
        course_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
        course_Place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coursePlace);
        course_Cost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseCosto);
    }
}


public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> titleList, ArrayList<String> lugarList, ArrayList<String> costoList, ArrayList<String> duracionList, ArrayList<String> aprobacionList, ArrayList<String> URLimagenList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.titleList = titleList;
    this.lugarList = lugarList;
    this.costoList = costoList;
    this.duracionList = duracionList;
    this.aprobacionList = aprobacionList;
    this.URLimagenList = URLimagenList;
}

@Override
public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list_items,parent, false);
    return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.course_Title.setText(titleList.get(position));
    holder.course_Place.setText(lugarList.get(position));
    holder.course_Cost.setText(costoList.get(position));
    Glide.with(context).load(URLimagenList.get(position)).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.course_Image);



}
```

Comment: just do it, it's straight forward. You can have the view holder implement the listener interface and use that object as the listener for clicks. Remember to set the layout to clickable and focusable.

Comment: `"How to add onClickListener() to a onBindViewHolder?"` do not do that - instead add `onClickListener` inside your  `SearchViewHolder` constructor

Answer (score 1):

Don't make click listener in BindViewHolder instead of make clicklistener in Adapter's ViewHolder.

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView course_Image;
        TextView course_Title, course_Place, course_Cost;

        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            course_Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseImage);
            course_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseTitle);
            course_Place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coursePlace);
            course_Cost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.courseCosto);
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Your logic

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
holder.showResultView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Your logic
        }
    });
```